# return all rows of a table including duplicate rows

Tags: sql

can  any one help by sharing query for retrieving all rows of a table including duplicate rows. 
i used group by with col name which contains duplicate values and gave count as greater than one, but zero records is returned

Comment: what is wrong with: `select * from <tablename>`?

Comment: try googling before posting it on SO

Comment: no , it doesnot come, if the table was that simple, why wont i try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get all rows, just use

`select * from tableName`

If you want to filter the duplicates out just add

`select distinct * from tableName`

if you want to group by, you can do:

```
select column1, column2 
sum(column1, column2) as sumCol
from table    
group by column1,column2
```

or using a window function

```
select *
sum(column1, column2) over (partition by column5) as sum
from table
```

Comment: Why add a GROUP BY example without using any aggregate functions?

Answer (score 0):

select * from master01.PRD_PRODUCTS t1
join master01.PRD_PRODUCTS  t2 on
t1. PRD_PROD_NBR= t2. PRD_PROD_NBR
group by t1. PRD_PROD_NBR

Answer (score -1):

Simply do `select * from tablename`.